# redirect all requests to subdomain to an appropriate folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have multiple clients that I have subdomains for
client1.example.com client2.example.com ... etc etc

now in my root directory I have one common code base and rest is different depending on clients

so in my root directory I have these folders
 mymainrepo client1 client2

mymainrepo contains all the common code

client1 contains multiple folders like cache dbsettings 
client2 contains multiple folders like cache dbsettings

But the content of cache and dbsettings is different for every client.
so what I want to do is if a request comes in for a client and it asks for a cache folder contenet, i want it to be served form that clients folder

so if a request is client1.example.com/cache
it will serve the contents from

```
doc root
    |
    |
     -------client1
                |
                |_______cache
```

and if the request is client2.example.com/cache
it will serve from

```
doc root
        |
        |
         -------client2
                    |
                    |_______cache
```

and so on and so on.

Any help will be appreciated
thanks

** EDITED **

ok so I tried this and this sorta works

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+)\.domain.com$[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [r=301,nc]
DirectoryIndex client1/index.html
```

problem is I want to have this dynamic instead of client1 hard coded

```
DirectoryIndex client1/index.html
```

I tried

DirectoryIndex %1/index.html

but that did not work

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you post your full .htaccess? Do you want this new rule to rewrite only `/cache/` URIs?

Answer (score 1):

You  can use something like the following

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+)\.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This will rewrite `client.domain.com/path` to the `/client` folder of your main document root. So if the request is `client.domain.com/cache` this will internally redirect it to `/client/cache` showing you the contents from that folder.

Comment: unfortunately it does nothing at all... no redirects... mod_rewrite is enabled and working fine. But these rules do not work

Comment: What happenes when you type `sub.domain.com` in your browser?  Do you get any server side error?  Also make sure the rule is at the top of your htaccess before any other Rewriting rules .